# Type inference failing within a case statement

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors

This is about as minimal a case as I could find.

```
import akka.actor.ActorDSL.Act
trait Foo[A]

object Foo {
  case class Str(str: String) extends Foo[String]
  case object Actor extends Foo[Act]

  def foo[A](f: Foo[A]): A = f match {
    case Str(string) => string
    case Actor => new Act {
      become { case e => println(e) }
    }
  }
}
```

This errors via

```
Foo.scala:12: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : akka.actor.ActorDSL.Act
[error]  required: A
[error]     case Actor => new Act {
[error]                   ^
```

The `Str` case is just there to show that type inference works in the normal usecase, but somehow Scala is "forgetting" that the `A` is supposed to be a specific type by the time that it checks the return type of the case statement.

Note that if you extract the partial function inside the `new Act` to a separate function, it compiles correctly again.

```
import akka.actor.ActorDSL.Act
trait Foo[A]

object Foo {
  case class Str(str: String) extends Foo[String]
  case object Actor extends Foo[Act]

  val partial: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case e => println(e)
  }

  def foo[A](f: Foo[A]): A = f match {
    case Str(string) => string
    case Actor => new Act {
      become(partial)
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Type inference is limited; the Scala compiler does not go so far that it understands that if you pass `Actor`, `A` should always be `Act`.

Comment: That's not actually true, though; see the `Str` case. It correctly infers that when you pass `Str`, a `Foo[String]`, that `A` should be `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a problem with your imports, because your example otherwise compiles correctly:

```
trait Foo[A]
trait Act

object Foo {
  case class Str(str: String) extends Foo[String]
  case object Actor extends Foo[Act]

  def foo[A](f: Foo[A]): A = f match {
    case Str(string) => string
    case Actor => new Act {}
  }
}
```

Tested in Scala 2.11.7.

Comment: Yeah, the type inference does work fine under normal cases. The bug specifically seems to be something to do with the `become()` function inside `Act`. I'll add some more detail about this to the question.